# Service layer in Web Services

Tags: java, web-services, service-layer

I'm a little confused about what service layer must contain (Web Services context).
In my application the service layer only has interfaces and their implementations that delegate operations to the domain layer (here are POJO'S and all the classes that do the domain logic).

In fact I have only one interface and one implementation like this:

The interface :

```
package org.myapp.services;

import org.myapp.domain.entities.User;

public interface IServices {
    public User getUserInfo(String userId);
}
```

And the implementation:

```
package org.myapp.services;

import org.myapp.domain.entities.User;
import org.myapp.domain.usermanagement.UserManager;

public class Services implements IServices{

    UserManager userManager;

    public Services() {
        userManager = new UserManager();
    }

    public User getUserInfo(String userId) {
        return userManager.getUserInfo(userId);
    }
}
```

(The UserManager class is belongs to the domain layer).

And the clients can access the web service using the url:
http://address/axis2/services/myapp/getUserInfo

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: You might consider using Data Transfer Objects (DTOs).  This abstracts the web service data model with the service layer data model